# Как из строки получить число в C?

Tags: c, преобразование-типов

Допустим: есть переменная `str_num`, хранящая в себе какое-либо число в виде строки. Например: `"122"`. Как мне присвоить новой переменной `int_num` значение `str_num`  в виде числа, а не строки?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Conversions_to_numeric_formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функциями [`atoi`, `atol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi), [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), например.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, как использовать. Примеры в документации мне непонятны.

Comment: Да ну! `int_num=atoi(str_num);` - это так непонятно?

Comment: прошу прощения, я посмотрел только `strtol`. Его я не понял. Спасибо за ответ, но у меня вё ещё не работает. https://repl.it/@don2quixote/Learning <- Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код, если не затруднит.

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev,  как раз `strtol()` и постарайтесь понять (именно ее нужно использовать во "взрослых" прогах)

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev, в вашем примере `char str_num = '1';` это не строка, правильно `char *str_num = "1";` или `char str_num[] = "1";`

Comment: @avp, Спасибо большое.